# How do I connect this hot plate

Tags: electrical, wiring, uk

This is in Germany, brand new flat.

The wall socket is:
[image]

The device has the following sticker:
[image]

But the blue and grey wires are linked:
[image]

Should I:

- separate the blue and grey and connect them with their respective colors in the socket
- connect them both in the blue
- connect them both in the grey

I am thinking they should both go in blue (neutral) as there are only 2 phases. Is that correct?

The panel has a 400V 63A breaker for this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your kitchen has a three-phase supply.
- Your hob can run on a single-phase to neutral (1N AC 32 A) or on two phases of a three-phase supply (2N AC 16 A).

Note that the current is split into two 16 A circuits for the three-phase supply. This is the one you want.

[image]

*Figure 1. Probable internal wiring. R1 and R2 each represent one or more hobs.*

Comment: So if I run on two phases, I can connect the black and brown in their respective phases and then the blue to neutral; but why is the third phase (grey) wire bundled with the neutral (blue)? Can I leave it floating?

Comment: Can you see my Figure 1?

Comment: That’s for single phase though, how can I connect it with the two phases?

Comment: L1, L2 and L3 are the three phases in your wall socket. I've coloured the wires to show you how the hob is wired internally and how to connect it to the wall. I've shown your hob connected to two phases.

Comment: So the hub has 2 phases, with brown and black wires and a blue neutral. In the sticker that comes with it, they indicate, for two phases, to connect these two colors (the second picture I sent). For some reason the cable comes with a third phase wire (grey). If we ignore the grey, I assume black->black, brown->brown, blue->blue; but then since the third phase wire is not used, what I am wondering about is of it can be left floating or is it better to hook it to neutral?

Comment: Can you not see that there are two circuits in the hot plate. One is brown and grey, connected from L1 to N. The other is black and blue, connected from L2 to N. Can you see that I have connected both blue and grey to N to match the 2N AC 16 A diagram on the label?

Comment: Ahhh yes, ok I get it now! Thanks